# How do remove white space on top and bottom of webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page and i have built a tabbed content area x 3. On the top there is a large white space and on the bottom there is a small white space. I am able to see there is a margin top of 100px, but when i change this to 0px, there is still a small white gap at the top. The bottom always shows a small white space. How do i remove this?

This is the page i am referring to:[Page with white space on top and bottom](https://nationalticketagency.com/demo/responsive.html)

Comment: Try adding margin 0 to the your body

Comment: You have a bunch of mixed content warnings (which can block the loading of resources) when you view the console.  You should fix those.

Comment: margin:0; is already added to the body in class html, body

Comment: mixed content issues i am aware of. need to call stylesheets and js via https. thanks for pointing out though. will fix later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the given page if you add/refactor the following styles with `margin: 0;` it will fix your problem:

```
.z-width960 #page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This fixes the top white space, but bottom white space still showing.

Comment: @MattGodwin Add `min-height: 100vh` to your `.parallax ` class.  Answer Updated

Comment: I applied the above fix and it works now. Not sure why bottom white space was showing still, maybe a refresh was needed. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer correct. Happy coding.

Comment: How do i mark your answer as correct? I am slightly new here :) I did click the up arrow.

Comment: Ok i figured it out. I clicked the check mark :) Thanks again!